# How to add to a number in a file?

Tags: c++, file, numbers, structure, addition

I am using this file:

```
cookie1
1
2
3
cookie2
4
5
6
cookie3
7
8
9
cookie4
10
11
12
cookie5
13
14
15
```

I need to get num from the user and pick use that to pick the cookie number that they chose and allow them to add a number to the quantity which is the first number after the cookie type.

Here is my code:

```
void AddQuantity (fstream &file)
{
char user_choice[SIZE];
int i = 1;
Cookies tempCookies;
int num;

file.open("cookie.dat", ios::in | ios::out | ios::app);
file.clear();
file.seekg(0L, ios::beg);

    file >> tempCookies.description;
    file >> tempCookies.quantity_sold;
    file >> tempCookies.cost;
    file >> tempCookies.price;

while (!file.eof())
{

    cout << i << ". " << tempCookies.description << endl;

    file >> tempCookies.description;
    file >> tempCookies.quantity_sold;
    file >> tempCookies.cost;
    file >> tempCookies.price;

    i++;
};
cout << endl;
file.clear();

cout << "Enter the number of the cookie type that you would like to modify: ";
cin >> num;
cout << endl;

file.seekg((num - 1)* sizeof(Cookies), ios::beg);

return;
}
```

Comment: I really believe the following passage needs to be edited: "I need to get num from the user and pick use that to pick the cookie number that they chose and allow them to add a number to the quantity which is the first number after the cookie type."

Comment: What problem are you facing...

Comment: Specifically, what are you having issues with?  Is it the `while (!file.eof())` *(which is incorrect)*?  Is it adding numbers?  Is it appending to a file?  Is it inserting into the middle of a file?

Comment: I'm not sure how to get to the specific quantity once the user has chosen a  number is my main problem, I'm also unsure how to replace the number in the file once I've added something to it.

Answer (score 0):

After the statement `file.seekg((num - 1)* sizeof(Cookies), ios::beg);`
you can now modify the cookie as

```
file.read( (char *)&tempCookies, sizeof(Cookies) );//used to read the required cookie
file.seekg((num - 1)* sizeof(Cookies), ios::beg);//shifting back file pointer by one cookie object 
tempCookies.quantity_sold = new_value;//updating the value
file.write( (char *)&tempCookies, sizeof(Cookies) );//writing the value to the file.
```